# Insert not working in custom hash function in cpp unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I am trying using the following construct of **unordered_map**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;


int width = 6;
int length = 6;
string parameters[] = {"0 0 0 1","6 6 5 6"};

struct co_ord {
  int x,y;
  int x1, y1;
  co_ord(int x, int y, int x1, int y1) : x(x), y(y), x1(x1), y1(y1) {}
};

struct co_ordHash {
  size_t operator()(const co_ord& key) const {
    return ((10+key.x)*100000000) + ((10+key.y)*1000000) + ((10+key.x1)*10000) + ((10+key.y1)*100);
  }
};


struct co_ordEqual {
  bool operator()(const co_ord& lhs, const co_ord& rhs) const {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y && lhs.x1 == rhs.x1 && lhs.y1 == rhs.y1;
  }
};

int maxPath(int x, int y, unordered_map<co_ord, bool, co_ordHash, co_ordEqual> barriers) {
  // unordered_map<co_ord, bool>::const_iterator iter;
  int sum = 0;
  if (x > width || y > length) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (x==width && y==length) {
    return 1;
  }

  co_ord *temp;
  temp = new co_ord(x, y, x+1, y);
  unordered_map<co_ord, bool, co_ordHash, co_ordEqual>::const_iterator iter1 = barriers.find(*temp);
  if (iter1 == barriers.end()) {
    sum = maxPath(x+1, y, barriers);
  }
  temp = new co_ord(x, y, x, y+1);
  unordered_map<co_ord, bool, co_ordHash, co_ordEqual>::const_iterator iter2 = barriers.find(*temp);
  if (iter2 == barriers.end()) {
    return sum + maxPath(x, y+1, barriers);
  }
  return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  string barrier[4];
  string delimiter = " ";
  co_ord *temp;
  unordered_map<co_ord, bool, co_ordHash, co_ordEqual> barriers;

  int i,j,k, para_len = sizeof(parameters)/sizeof(parameters[0]);

  for (i = 0; i < para_len; i++) {
    j = k = 0;
    while (j<4) {
      barrier[j] = "";
      while (parameters[k] != " " || parameters[k]!= "\n") {
        barrier[j] += parameters[k];
        k++;
      }
      barrier[j] += '\n';
      j++;
    }
    temp = new co_ord(stoi(barrier[0]), stoi(barrier[1]), stoi(barrier[2]), stoi(barrier[3]));
    barriers.insert(temp, false); // here is the problem
  }

  cout<<maxPath(0,0, barriers);

  return 0;
}
```

I cannot make an insert into the function. Can anyone help me with that? 
I get this error:

```
    avoidroads_dp.cc:79:14: error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
    barriers.insert(temp, false);
    ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? How do you know?

Comment: @AlanStokes getting compile time error. updated question.

Comment: That is not the entire error.  Please include entire error.  If you understood what mattered in the error, you would not have to ask here.

Comment: @Yakk that is it. it is entire error. there is nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: No line number?  No warnings above and below?  No "blah is of type blah"?  What compiler?

Comment: I have already mentioned that line number in my code, and I already said its an error. I pasted the error line. Hope that conveys the same idea in better way.

Comment: For people who knows stuffs gets it at right place. Got the answer accepted before editing! And thanks for down voting. I strongly believe that stackover flow is a hub of arrogant people. Thats what makes Quora a better tool these days.

Comment: It's also arrogant to expect people to solve your problem for you without you attempting to provide a minimal example, or specifying the tools you're using or the details of the error your seeing. Most compilers try to give helpful information for such errors; so either you're using an old compiler or you're ignoring information designed to help you.

Comment: An example of the kind of information you omitted for whatever reason: `[Note] candidate is: In file included from main.cpp [Note] void deckOfCards::shuffle(std::vector<Card>&)` almost all compilers dump a pile of useful notes after each error.  [MCVE] is a link to an on-site set of advice on how to ask a good question.  At 100s of reputation, I expect better than "here is a copy paste of code, it did not work, help please".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use std::make_pair to insert data. There is one more thing: according to your template signature you use co_ord type as key, but you try adding pointer to co_ord object. You should change your signature or reject using pointer as key. 
 Here is an example of fixed string

```
barriers.insert(make_pair(*temp, false));
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! It worked like a gem.